# Microsoft Azure Cogntive Services error 404 (not found)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

when creating a Cognitive Service (text analytics) I am getting an 404 error (not found), when testing the URL: https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0

I also tested other domains with same result. Does anybody have and idea? Thanks! Hugo.

Comment: Tested these 2 url: 
https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases 
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases 
Error 404

Answer (score 0):

The only three valid endpoints are documented here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c6.

If you try those URLs in the browser they won't work. They only respond to POST requests. You can use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to try them out.